# Calculate price by on row insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on an assignment from my university where I have to create a little database. I have to calculate a fee based on a class price and a discount. What would be the ideal way to do this? Create a trigger on an insert?

The ERD:
[image]

So the enrolment.fee_paid is the price of class_type.fee - the membership.discount. The Trigger I would have to write seems very nested and rather chaotic to read and that is why I am wondering if there would be a more elegant solution.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What other options are available? What's the thing that's invoking the insert?

Comment: I'm not sure you have to trigger an event, *per se*. You could calculate the fee paid then do the insert. But you could do it with an event trigger as well. Why would it be nested or chaotic? Is that information not available at the time the enrollment record is inserted?